# handle transaction in Linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, transactions

I am implementing the asp.net MVC web application, where i am using the Linq to Sql to manipulate the data in database. but in my one of action, i want to insert multiple table entries which are depends upon each other by referring previous insertion Id's. So i just wnat to know how to handle the transaction, like begin transaction, commit,rollback and all like in ADO.net. how to manage this. what if one of insertion get crashed in the middle of manipulation?

Note:- I am not using the Stored procedures here. I am using Lambda expressions and methods. Also these are use in different manager classes. 
**Example:**
For Create Subject - used method in SubjectManager class to insert subject infor, that returns subject Id. within this subjectid i am inserting the let say its chapters with another method in manager class  as ChapterManager. which again returns the ChapterId, on base of this chapeter Id , inserting the Topics of chapter. that again uses Topic manager same like above.in each manger class i am creating dataContext object for the same. and I am controlling all this within a single action in my controller. but worrying about the transaction management. how I can use here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(DataContext ctx = new MyDataContext())
    {
        ctx.Subject.Add(subject);
        Chapter chapter = new Chapter();
        chapter.SubjectId = subject.Id;
        ctx.SubmitChanges();
        ctx.Chapter.Add(chapter);
        ctx.SubmitChanges();
        scope.Complete() // if it all worked out
    }
}
```

From the System.Transactions namespace I believe.

Comment: Thanks , is it would work for all entire data manipulations ?

Comment: yes, Everything within the TransactionScope is wrapped in a transaction. The only thing you'll need to be careful of is the datacontext. I think you can only have one within a scope. I'll update the code to show a bit more info.

Comment: You're going to have problems calling multiple SubmitChanges within the same DataContext block. The built-in change tracking mechanism cannot and does not guarantee the integrity of the data once changes are made, because it doesn't update the objects after the change is made.

Comment: Yep, you are correct Neil. I've upvoted your answer in preference to mine and removed my code. Thanks :)

Comment: Self-vandalism rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action

Answer (score 1):

The DataContext already includes an embedded transaction object.  For example, let's say you are placing a new order for a customer. You can set up your model so that the following code updates both the Customer AND Order table with a single SubmitChanges.  As long as a foreign key relationship exists between the two tables, the embedded transaction object handles both the Customer update and the Order insert in the same transaction.  Using a TransactionScope object to encase a single DataContext is redundant:

```
using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
{
    Order order = new Order();

    order.ProductID = 283564;
    order.Quantity = 7;
    order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

    Customer customer = dc.Customers.Single(c => c.CustomerID == 6);

    customer.LastUpdate = order.OrderDate;
    customer.Orders.Add(order);

    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```